# GDB, asm: how to alias name with memory adress

Tags: assembly, gdb

When i disassembly code in GDB i get standard asm output like:

**mov [ebp-0x1] 0x5**

Is it possible to manually set name 'var1' for ebp-0x1 so it displays in the current debugging session:

**mov [var1] 0x5**

Comment: You could probably set a GDB var to the absolute address `$ebp-1`.  That would snapshot the EBP value when you defined `var1`, though, so you'd need to redefine it on other calls to the same function with a different stack pointer.